# Can't use IPython console in PyCharm

Tags: console, pycharm, ipython

I wanted to use `ipython` as default console in `Pycharm` but it doesn't work.

I have selected use `ipython` when available in the console option available under Build,Deployment and Execution in Settings. Did the same in Default Settings also. But it doesn't seem to work.

I am using `Python 3.6.3` , `IPython 6.2.1` and `PyCharm Professional 2017.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because IPython is not recognized as a package in your project interpreter.

This usually happens when you configure a `virtualenv` for your project, but don't check the `Inherit global site-packages` checkbox.

Fixing is quite easy:
Go to `Settings -> Project: <project name> -> Project interpreter`
At the bottom of the packages list you should see a `+` sign.
Press that button, find `ipython` and install it.

On the next time you'll open your console, IPython will be detected and used automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You have not installed IPython package.

Do this:

File → Settings... → Project *your_project* → Python Interpreter

then click the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the right-hand vertical toolbar (see the red arrow in the picture):

[image]

and from the new popup window select and install `ipython` package:

[image]

Finally, restart your Python Console.